# Vuetify v0.17.6: How to get the autocomplete text inside v-select

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm using VueJS v2.5.13 and Vuetify v0.17.6.

I'm building a select with autocomplete functionality and whenever the user types something that's not on the list they'll be able to see a action to create a new option as the code below shows:

```
<template>
<v-select prepend-icon="view_list" :items="options" label="Quick searches" v-model="selected" item-text="label" autocomplete :search-value="inputText" clearable dense>
    <template slot="item" slot-scope="data">
        <v-flex xs12>
            <v-layout>
                <v-layout justify-start fill-height align-content-center>
                    <span>{{data.item.label}}</span>
                </v-layout>
                <v-layout justify-end row>
                    <v-icon color="success" @click="edit(data)">mod_edit</v-icon>
                    <v-icon color="error" @click="del(data)">delete_forever</v-icon>
                </v-layout>
            </v-layout>
        </v-flex>
    </template>
    <template slot="no-data">
        <v-container>
            <v-layout row>
                <v-layout justify-start fill-height align-content-center>
                    Create new search
                </v-layout>
                <v-layout justify-end>
                    <v-icon color="success" @click="create()">add</v-icon>
                </v-layout>
            </v-layout>
        </v-container>
    </template>
</v-select>
```

How can i access the text the user is typing to create a new 'quick search' using the user autocomplete text as label?

Comment: Is it not just the value of `inputText`?

Comment: Sadly it's not. As an event i'm able to get the autcomplete text if i add a callback to @change:searchInput. But i can't find a way to bind that data to a prop or variable

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can bind it by using `:search-input.sync`:

```
<v-select :search-input.sync="searchInput"
```

add `searchInput` variable to your `data`

```
data() {
    return {
         //...
         searchInput: "",
    };
},
```

[example pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aqdZJR)

Additionally, if it seems "laggy" that's because of `debounce-search`
 property, which adds 200ms delay. You can change it to 0 if you want to catch value every time it's changed:

```
:debounce-search="0"
```

Comment: Very elegant solution indeed. Thanks!

Comment: So a watch is needed if I want to do ajax search query based on this input change

Comment: Also put "autocomplete" in v-select to actually type anything to search

Answer (score 2):

In the template:

```
<v-select
    :items="itemList"
    :search-input.sync="searchInput"
    item-text="name"
    autocomplete
/>
```

In the script

```
data: () => ({
    itemList: [{name: 'John'}, {name: 'Doe'}],
    searchInput: ""
}),
```

Comment: Autocomplete saved my day. @traxo answer above is complete, he just missed autocomplete

Comment: Any idea why it may not work? i do exactly the same but my searchInput is not getting update

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a more efficient way with Vuetify, but you should be able to just use `v-on:input=handleInput` with a `handleInput` method (or whatever) to receive the value.

Comment: Using `.sync` seems simpler. See my answer. Thoughts?