# Input custom text into v-select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a v-select in my project, with set of items, which are coming from my local storage. What i want to achieve is to allow user to input some data in v-select (some data, what do not exist in my storage or items), as well as selecting data from items of v-select and allow them to save it. I tried to do it from @change, but no luck for me. Is it any way to do this properly with vuetify/vue, or i should use some additional libraries? Here is my code of my v-select

```
           <v-select
          item-text="title"
          item-value="title"
          value="source.position"
          label="position"
          dense
          autocomplete
          :items="getPositions()"
          @change="jobPositionUpdate">
        </v-select>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you please show us your component too? Maybe even a working copy...

Comment: is `jobPositionUpdate` being called when the select box changes? It should

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48500587/1981247) is related.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to me you need to use combobox. According to [Vuetify Website](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox#combobox) "With Combobox, you can allow a user to create new values that may not be present in a provided items list."

```
<v-combobox
   v-model="selected"
   item-text="title"
   item-value="title"
   value="source.position"
   label="position"
   dense
   :items="getPositions()"
   @change="jobPositionUpdate">
</v-combobox>
```

Adding a v-model helps with tracking all the things user has selected and/or added to combobox.

Another tip is that using autocomplete in v-select is deprecated. [see](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes#autocomplete). You can use `<v-autocomplete>` instead

Comment: how do you actually get the new value that has been input. ie if I input 'Sales' and it does not exist in the list of items, how do I handle the new value?

Comment: I have a combo box, and I type a new value but can't enter it nor do anything else

Comment: With Combobox, you can allow a user to create new values that may not be present in a provided items list. I can't tell without seeing your code